# Extreme Value Theory - domains of attraction and techniques for evaluting a limit

Tags: extreme-value, gumbel-distribution

We consider the gamma uniform G distribution as specified by
Torabi and Montazeri:
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{\Gamma (a)}\frac{g(x)}{[1-G(x)]^2}\left[\frac{G(x)}{1-G(x)}\right]^{a-1}\exp\left[\frac{G(x)}{1-G(x)}\right]$$
where $G$ is a valid c.d.f., $g$ the corresponding p.d.f. and $a > 0$.

My question is this:

> If $G$ belongs to the Gumbel domain of attraction, that is, if there
>   exists $\gamma(t)>0$ such that $$\lim_{t \uparrow
> w(G)}\frac{1-G(t+x\gamma(t))}{1-G(t)}=e^{-x},$$
>   for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, and if the upper end point $w(G) = w(F)$, then is it true that $F$ belongs to the same (Gumbel) domain of attraction as $G$?

The sticking point here is the exponential term, as we consider 
$$\lim_{t \uparrow
w(F)}\frac{1-F(t+x\gamma(t))}{1-F(t)}=\lim_{t \uparrow
w(F)}\frac{f(t+x\gamma(t))(1+x\gamma^\prime(t))}{f(t)},$$
where the equality follows from L'Hopital's rule. Now this gives rise to the term $$\lim_{t \uparrow
w(G)}\frac{\exp\left[\frac{G(t+x\gamma(t))}{1-G(t+x\gamma(t))}\right]}{\exp\left[\frac{G(t)}{1-G(t)}\right]}.$$
How do I evaluate this limit?

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand the question; "if there exists ... such that $lim...$ for all $x$" -  what does this mean? Should that limit be equal to something, or must that limit exist for all $x$?

Comment: Fixed the mistake.

Comment: What is $w(G)$?  Is this the upper end point in the sense that $t \uparrow w(G)$ implies $G(t) \uparrow 1$?  Or do you mean that $t \uparrow w(G)$ implies $G(t) \uparrow w$?  Or do you mean something else?

Comment: In the definition of the *gamma uniform G* distribution, a minus sign should be found in the exponentiated bracket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Preliminary interpretation:** Your question does not clearly specify what you mean by $w(G)$, but you say that this is an "upper end point"of the distribution.  I am going to assume that you mean that $t \uparrow w(G)$ implies $G(t) \uparrow 1$.  My answer proceeds on this basis.

---

To simplify the notation in this problem we treat $\gamma$ as fixed and denote $G_x(t) \equiv G(t+x\gamma(t))$.  We then define the functions:

$$E_x(t) \equiv \frac{1-G_x(t)}{1-G(t)} \quad \quad \quad \bar{E}_x(t) \equiv \frac{G_x(t)}{G(t)}.$$

These functions are related by:

$$\bar{E}_x(t) = \frac{1- E_x(t)(1-G(t))}{G(t)}.$$

By assumption, for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ you have $\lim_{t \uparrow w(G)} E_x(t)= e^{-x}$.  By the [composition law of limits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function#Limits_of_compositions_of_functions) (and assuming the required continuity for it to apply) we also have:

$$\lim_{t \uparrow w(G)} \bar{E}_x(t) = \lim_{t \uparrow w(G)} \frac{1- e^{-x}(1-G(t))}{G(t)}.$$

We now define and simplify the function:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
H(t,x) 
&\equiv \frac{G_x(t)}{1-G_x(t)} - \frac{G(t)}{1-G(t)} \\[6pt]
&= \frac{1-G(t)}{1-G_x(t)} \cdot \frac{G_x(t)}{G(t)} \cdot \frac{G(t)}{1-G(t)} - \frac{G(t)}{1-G(t)} \\[6pt]
&= \frac{G(t)}{1-G(t)} \Bigg[ \frac{1-G(t)}{1-G_x(t)} \cdot \frac{G_x(t)}{G(t)} - 1 \Bigg] \\[6pt]
&= \frac{G(t)}{1-G(t)} \Bigg[ \frac{\bar{E}_x(t)}{E_x(t)} - 1 \Bigg]. \\[6pt]
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

Hence, applying the composition law again yields:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
\lim_{t \uparrow w(G)} (1-G(t)) \cdot H(t,x) 
&= \lim_{t \uparrow w(G)} G(t) \Bigg[ \frac{\bar{E}_x(t)}{E_x(t)} - 1 \Bigg] \\[6pt]
&= \lim_{t \uparrow w(G)} G(t) \Bigg[ \frac{1- e^{-x}(1-G(t))}{e^{-x} G(t)} - 1 \Bigg] \\[6pt]
&= \lim_{t \uparrow w(G)} G(t) \Bigg[ \frac{1- e^{-x} + e^{-x} G(t) - e^{-x} G(t)}{e^{-x} G(t)} \Bigg] \\[6pt]
&= \lim_{t \uparrow w(G)} G(t) \cdot \frac{1- e^{-x}}{e^{-x} G(t)}  \\[6pt]
&= \frac{1- e^{-x}}{e^{-x}} \\[6pt]
&= e^{x}-1. \\[6pt]
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

Now, the limit you want to find is $\lim_{t \uparrow w(G)} \exp(H(t,x))$.  This limit is infinity, but there is a related limit that may be useful:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
\lim_{t \uparrow w(G)} \exp(H(t,x))^{\exp(1-G(t))} 
&= \lim_{t \uparrow w(G)} \exp( (1-G(t)) \cdot H(t,x)) \\[6pt]
&= \exp(e^x-1). \\[6pt]
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

Comment: The next to last line doesn't make sense to me. Could you explain the jump from a limit of the form $e^{(a/b)}/e^{(c/d)}$ to $e^{(a/c)}/e^{(b/d)}$?

Comment: Sorry, that's a mistake - I will edit to fix.

Comment: When can we expect the edit?

Comment: @Will: I have now made a major edit to correct the previous misinterpretation of your question.  It should be okay now.